# How to hide a Annotation Panel in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, pdf

I have downloaded the PDF Annotation Editor code and I want to invisible the Annotation panel when the window loaded. I have tried to search for a Hide method but I couldn't find it.

Here is original code:

```
AnnotPanel = [AnnotationPanel sharedAnnotationPanel];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(annotationChanged:) 
        name: AnnotationPanelAnnotationDidChangeNotification object: annotPanel];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
[AnnotPanel OrderOut:self];
```